# ZendDb2: Use NOW() on update query

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-db

I am trying to do this query using ZendDb 2 but it does not seem to work.

```
$db->update(['SentDate' => 'NOW()'], ['Id' => $request->Id]);
```

On ZendDb 1 we could use Zend_Db_Expr but I can't find a workaround for the new version.

Does anybody know how to achieve this using ZendDb 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression like this.

```
$db->update(['SentDate' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression('NOW()')], ['Id' => $request->Id])
```

Comment: Thanks @otto-sandström that was what I was searching for.